# State of PPK support in iOS DJI SDK 4.14

Tags: dji-sdk

DJI Mobile SDK version 4.14 for iOS has added support for PPK. A new method to enable PPK has been added called "setPPKModeEnabled". If PPK is enabled through this method and a waypoint mission is run on a Phantom 4 RTK, the drone satellite observation file are created but no images are recorded. Can a DJI engineer give some insight into this issue? The camera mode was set to shootPhoto when this method was called. There was also a SD card in the drone.
Is PPK actually implemented in iOS mobile SDK 4.14? There is no mention of PPK in the SDK release notes.